# can't get bootstrap to centre right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a joomla 3 template so I have to use bootstrap 2. I am a bit new to BS and want to learn.

There are 4 sizes, and 3 of them are working well. I want the third smallest to go into each block being full size (like the smallest) but I am having problems getting things centered. I have used firebug to copy over the styles for row, span and container - but something is wrong.

the content is in a .span2 and I have this css

```
.row {
    margin-left:0px;
}

.container {
    background-color:#F0FA5A;

}

.span2 {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    margin-left:0;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

here's a ss:
[image: its not centered]

As you can see the container (yellow) is centered, but the content isn't.

So if I put the .row margin-left to -20px to pull it back the row becomes too wide thus:
[image: its not centered]

If someone could suggest what I need to do please to get it right

I have also tried setting the container width to auto, with margins:auto - now its perfect, excep

You can see it at www.fct.ee-web.co.uk

thanks

Comment: Put all of your content inside the yellow container.

Comment: all content is inside the yellow container

Comment: Include a jsfiddle of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap.css you can see

> [class*="span"]
>
> value :
>
> margin-left: 20 px;

you can edit it or override it with !importion;

Comment: I have a separate template.css file which I am using to override the core files. So I added !important into the css above for the .span2 margin-left:0px !important - was that right? It didn't make any difference?

Comment: http://s11.postimg.org/gj7qpk9oj/Capture.png

you can see this. I have disable properties margin-left: 20px;
your web site was changed :3

Comment: thakns - yes I see it. And that made me realise that I hadn't set the margin-left on the .span12 to 0. I did that in my tempate and Bob's your uncle. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

put a `margin-left:0` on the mainContent when  have the proper size

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
   .mainContent {
     margin-left:0px;
   }
}
```

Comment: that works! Thanks - don't know why since the margin on .mainContent was 0 anyway (or rather i suppose I should say hadn't been set)